# Problems in using geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

Until the beginning of this week I was using the geopandas package fine, but today when I tried to import it I got the following error:

```
import geopandas
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 109, in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 95, in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py", line 216, in <module>
    import rtree  # noqa
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rtree/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree, Index  # noqa
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rtree/core.py", line 77, in <module>
    rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: python3: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum
```

And now all my old codes are with the same error. Has anything changed in geopandas? I tried uninstalling and installing different versions but the error persists. Currently i'm using python 3.10.6 and geopandas 0.11.1.

Update: I updated the rtree package version it worked.

Comment: does `import rtree` fail?  I'm using same version of python and geopandas, rtree is 1.0.0

Comment: @RobRaymond I was using rtree 0.9.7. I updated to 1.0.0 and now everything is working. Thank you